# Cant create Eclipse WindowBuilder class

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

I installed the WindowBuilder plugin for Eclipse Oxygen.

[image]

When I right click on the src package of a project -> Other... however, I do not see the WindowBuilder Folder where I could create a SwingBuilder or SWTBuilder class.

I tried reinstalling it over the marketplace and the Install New Software option, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem, but it was pretty complicated (for me) and I dont know if you have to follow all steps to make it work.

My steps:

1) I updated from java 11 to java 14
2) I uninstalled eclipse oxygen and installed the newest eclipse version (2020-03)
3) I installed the WindowBuilder plugin and it worked

Note:
As far as I know, you need another plugin to make java14 work in eclipse. I downloaded Subclipse to do that.